# How to resize Firefox icon on desktop?

Tags: 16.04, firefox, icons, gnome-classic

Firefox 59.0.1 (64-bit) Firefox icon on desktop changes to abnormal size 128px, whereas it was 48px. This changes seems happen after  one of countless Firefox updates. When right click on icon, there is 'Resize Icon' option, it add guidelines around icon, but it not allow to resize. What is simple method to resize icon without a lot of manipulations or reinstalling application?
GNOME Flashback session.

Comment: What desktop environment are you using?

Comment: `/usr/bin/gnome-session`

Comment: Perhaps just deleting the icon and making a new one might do the trick.

Comment: Already tried this, not help. Deleted, then copied firefox app into the Desktop, but same effect: huge 128px icon, which is completely useless.

Answer (score 0):

1. Over the desktop Firefox icon right click → *Properties*
2. Select Basic tab
3. Left click on the Firefox icon.
4. Select path: `/usr/share/icons/elementary-xfce/apps/48/firefox.png`

Done!

Comment: there is no `elementary-xfce` folder in my system.

Comment: @triwo just substitute the path to your environment which you use for example  `/usr/share/icons/hicolor/48x48/apps/firefox.png`

Answer (score 0):

you could use gimp to scale it but firefox should have a 48x48 icon, you could try to copy it

```
mkdir -p ~/.icons/hicolor/48x48/apps
cp -v /usr/lib/firefox/browser/chrome/icons/default/default48.png \
    ~/.icons/hicolor/48x48/apps/firefox.png
```

[see firefox for linux from mozilla](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/showthread.php?p=5845618#post5845618)

thought it could be a gnome bug